# Synonyms of synonyms should be "collapsed"

Tags: feature-request, support, tag-synonyms, moderator-tools

These two tag synonyms are active at the moment:

- [thread](/questions/tagged/thread) -> [threads](/questions/tagged/threads)
- [threads](/questions/tagged/threads) -> [multithreading](/questions/tagged/multithreading)

The first synonym should be changed to [thread](/questions/tagged/thread) -> [multithreading](/questions/tagged/multithreading).

Probably completely automating such adjustments wouldn't be a good idea in case of bad synonyms (or cyclic relationships), but detecting and highlighting such cases for 
moderator intervention could be a good idea.

<sub>FYI: Currently a [thread](/questions/tagged/thread) tag on a question is rewritten to [threads](/questions/tagged/threads), not directly to [multithreading](/questions/tagged/multithreading).</sub>

Comment: I took care of the specific `[thread]` example.  Nice catch.