# Tag wiki Stats - "created" showing with wrong date calculation

Tags: bug, tags, tag-wiki, dates

In any tag's info page, under the **Stats** section the created detail is displaying. But the period is displaying wrongly.

For an example the [moderator-tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/moderator-tools/info) tag was created on **[2011-07-31](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/100467/revisions)** (also found in the tooltip of Stats), so the tag's duration period should be **[5 years, 11 months](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=31&m1=07&y1=2011&d2=30&m2=6&y2=2017)**. But in the **Stats** section it is displaying as **7 years, 1 month**. The calculation is wrong.

> [image: Moderator-tools created details]

I have verified for most of the tags and the period is displaying wrongly in the tag-wiki Stats section.

Comment: I don't know if there is a need to explicitly mention, but I want to add that this seems to be a network-wide problem (e.g. I checked StackOverflow and Travel.SE).

Comment: Related SEDE query: https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/840451/creation-date-for-a-tag

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the world of confusing *Created* stats about when a tag is ***Created***. IMO the information included in your question is not entirely (100%) correct:

- The date of `2011-07-31 19:39` (as shown in the image of your question), is the timestamp of the [first revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/100467/revisions) of the ***tag wiki excerpt***.
- The tag [moderation-tools](/questions/tagged/moderation-tools) itself, already existed on `Aug 8 '10 at 13:11`. The proof of that is included in [revision 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/60113/1) of the question titled [Synonyms of synonyms should be "collapsed"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60113/286501) (which is about `6 years and 10 months` after you posted your question, and only 3 months after those `7 years and 1 month` as in your question's image). I've not been able to find an even older question (yet ...), but I'm pretty confident that there is still an older question which either *used to have* that tag, or got deleted already, and in which the tag [moderation-tools](/questions/tagged/moderation-tools) was ***first added*** (with an empty tag excerpt).

#### Another example

This is indeed a *network-wide problem* (as in the comment from [ahmedus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/361230/ahmedus) below the question).
Consider what happened to the [group](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/group/info) tag (on Drupal.SE):

1. [This question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/197618/39516) is the very first question (timestamp question was asked), in which the "group" tag was added. I have no idea how to "proof" (via some query/sort) that this question indeed is the very first question with that tag. But I just know/remember that question when it happened (also because it is one of my favorit tags ...).
2. However, only in [revision 6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/197618/revisions) of it the "group" tag got added. So from that very moment on, an EMPTY group tag got created (timestamp of the revision = `Sep 13 '16 at 23:51`).
3. The next day, at `Sep 14 '16 at 6:07`, "I" created [revision 1](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/214752/1) of the tag wiki excerpt fro the group tag, as shown in [this revision history](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/214752/revisions).

With the above in mind, have a look again at the tag info page for the [group tag on Drupal.SE](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/group/info): the timestamp shown within "created" (= `Sep 14 '16 at 6:07` if you hoover over it ...) is **`the timestamp of the very first revision of the tag wiki excerpt`**.

#### Recommended correction

IMO that "Created" timestamp is wrong (or at least misleading) and should instead be the timestamp of the revision 6 of the original question. Or as an alternative (quick win?): adapt the 'Created' label to something like 'Tag excerpt created').