# Tag wiki creation time doesn't match actual date

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, tag-wiki

For example, https://stackoverflow.com/tags/html/info

> [image]

AFAIK, it's not 2020 right now.

Comment: I'd say the "10 years ago" is actually correct, and it should be 2008 instead of 2010, given SO started in 2008.

Comment: @Floern that's what I said.

Comment: @Floern That date is for when the tag *wiki* was created, not the tag itself. The timestamp is correct. Not sure where it's getting 10 years from.

Comment: @animuson It could be when the *tag* was created.

Comment: For those who wonder what the "10 years" refers to (such as @animuson ?): refer to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306949/286501 (disclosure: "my" answer).