# The "creation date" shown in the tag-info shows incorrect date (AFAICT the date when the tag-info was created)

Tags: bug, status-review, tags, tag-wiki, tag-creation

The tag-info for a tag contains some stats in the right sidebar. At least in some cases,<sup>1</sup> it says: "created .... ago by ". (And the timestamp shows the exact date if you hover above it.)

As far as I can tell, the date shown there isn't actually the date when the tag was created - in the instances that I've checked, the date/time seems to correspond to the creation of the tag-info.

There is a rather old bug report: ["created" date and user displayed on tag wiki refer to different events](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250398). It is tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). So maybe it was marked as completed prematurely - or maybe the bug regressed.

---

Some random examples:

- The tag [geometry](/questions/tagged/geometry) on Mathematics. The [tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/geometry/info) says 2011-03-15, the [Taxonomist badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=17) was awarded in August 2010. The tag-excerpt was [created in March 2011](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/27169/revisions). On the [site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) you can see that there were some questions with this tag in 2010: [18](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/18), [51](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/51), [59](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/59).
- The tag [homology](/questions/tagged/homology) on MathOverflow. The [tag-info](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/homology/info) says 2017-05-12, the [Taxonomist badge](https://mathoverflow.net/help/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=1) was awarded in October 2009. The tag-info was [created in May 2017](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/269637/revisions). On [the site](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/homology) or [from SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1105163/questions-which-had-the-given-tag-including-the-editor-who-added-it?tagname=homology) you can find some questions from 2009: [415](https://mathoverflow.net/q/415),  [590](https://mathoverflow.net/q/590),  [640](https://mathoverflow.net/q/640).
- The tag [bayesian](/questions/tagged/bayesian) on CrossValidated. The [tag-info](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/bayesian/info) says 2011-12-27, the [Taxonomist badge](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=8) was awarded in December 2010. The tag-info  was [created in December 2011](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/20258/revisions). On [the site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bayesian) or [from SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/1105163/questions-which-had-the-given-tag-including-the-editor-who-added-it?tagname=bayesian) you can find some posts which had this tag in 2010: [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/1), [22](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/22), [39](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/39).

Other related posts:

- [Tag wiki Stats - "created" showing with wrong date calculation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297857) (from 2017);
- [Tag wiki creation time doesn't match actual date](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315251) (from 2018).

---

<sup>1</sup>See also: [Show a tag's creator on the tag wiki page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108239) and
[What are the criteria for a tag creator's userid to be shown or not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306935)

---

Screenshot from Mathematics Stack Exchange:

[image: Screenshot from Mathematics Stack Exchange]

Screenshot from MathOverflow:

[image: Screenshot from MathOverflow]

Screenshot from CrossValidated:

[image: Screenshot from CrossValidated]